# Using Join on an update query, updating on rows rather than columns

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I need a query to achieve second table result, If it is possible, Please describe it in SQL SERVER and MYSQL database
I want to update the meta_value of rows where meta_key is bankaccount with the corresponding meta_value from rows where meta_key is iban.

Before the update (original `example_table`):

| document_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iban | IBAN123456 |
| 1 | bankaccount | ACCT987654 |
| 2 | iban | IBAN555555 |
| 2 | bankaccount | ACCT444444 |
| 3 | iban | IBAN888888 |
| 3 | bankaccount | ACCT333333 |

After running the SQL update query:

| document_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iban | IBAN123456 |
| 1 | bankaccount | IBAN123456 |
| 2 | iban | IBAN555555 |
| 2 | bankaccount | IBAN555555 |
| 3 | iban | IBAN888888 |
| 3 | bankaccount | IBAN888888 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the `meta_value` of rows where `meta_key` is `bankaccount` with the corresponding `meta_value` from rows where `meta_key` is `iban`.

Here's a SQL query to achieve this - MySQL:

```sql
UPDATE example_table AS p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT document_id, meta_value AS iban
    FROM example_table
    WHERE meta_key = 'iban'
) AS p2 ON p1.document_id = p2.document_id
SET p1.meta_value = p2.iban
WHERE p1.meta_key = 'bankaccount';
```

SQL Server:

```sql
UPDATE p1
SET p1.meta_value = p2.iban
FROM example_table AS p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT document_id, meta_value AS iban
    FROM example_table
    WHERE meta_key = 'iban'
) AS p2 ON p1.document_id = p2.document_id
WHERE p1.meta_key = 'bankaccount';
```

Explanation:

1. The `p1` table is the alias for `example_table`, and `p2` is the alias for the subquery.
2. The subquery selects `document_id` and `meta_value` where `meta_key` is `'iban'`.
3. The main query uses an `INNER JOIN` to match `document_id` between `p1` and the subquery `p2`.
4. It then updates `meta_value` in `p1` with the `iban` from `p2` where `meta_key` is `'bankaccount'`.

Remember to back up your database before running any update queries, and test them in a safe environment first!